# In Vuetify's checkbox component, How to change disabled checkbox's box color?

Tags: css, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify.js as UI framework of Nuxt.js,
I want to change the color of checkbox when check box disabled value change "false".
I thought if I change the value of the part corresponding to the checkbox with CSS, I could change the color of checkbox. But it didn't work.
Could anyone advise me?
My code is following code.

```
    <template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="4">
            <v-checkbox
              :label="`Checkbox A:${checkboxA}`"
              v-model="checkboxA"></v-checkbox>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="4">
            <v-checkbox
              :label="`Checkbox B:${checkboxB}`"
              :disabled="!checkboxA"></v-checkbox>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue{
  checkboxA:boolean = false
  checkboxB:boolean = false
  checkboxC:boolean = false
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.div ::v-deep .v-input--selection-controls__input{
  background: gray;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `scoped` in `style` is a bit tricky. With scoped, the parent component's styles will not leak into child components. You can use the deep selector `>>>` (like explained [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)) but I think this solution is not the best. Css is better using the BEM notation. In your case, I would do :

```
 <template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-container class="Card__container">
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="4">
            <v-checkbox
              :label="`Checkbox A:${checkboxA}`"
              v-model="checkboxA"></v-checkbox>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="4">
            <v-checkbox
              :label="`Checkbox B:${checkboxB}`"
              :disabled="!checkboxA"></v-checkbox>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
...
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.Card__container {
    .v-input--selection-controls__input{
      background: gray;
    }
}
</style>
```

Thanks to that, no risk of conflict with the other components.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone still has this issue. Instead of using `disabled` prop, you can use the `readonly` prop and still be able to set `colour="success"` or any other colour you want.

Comment: And note: `v-simple-checkbox` has no `readonly` prop, use `v-checkbox` instead.